# Implementing Server sided Datatables in Symfony with "action columns"

Tags: javascript, symfony, datatables

In my Symfony project I use Datatables.

They all have some ordinary columns with data but there is always one that holds actions like "edit", "details" or even custom icons and images with colors that depend on some conditions of the entity. Twig was a real good friend in doing this. It built the routes and switched colors by if statements an so on.

Now I'm fiddling around with server sided processing. Made a demo table with some entity data, built a controller, a repository, the js code and even implemented pipelining to reduce AJAX calls. Works perfectly - looking beautiful.

But what do I do with the column which holds the actions? Should I really build all the code twig created for me earlier in the controller passing complete html code to the table? I didn't even try it by now because to me it seems like really bad practice. Also it must become really ugly when I start dealing with webpack assets.

Any tips, thought or solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

you should implement your buttons in javascript and depending on the response from the server show the appropriate button.

Symfony has several DataTable bundle that works beautifully and hassle free. here is a suggestion:

https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/